# Trying to add content inside a DIV

Tags: jquery

This is my jquery, Where i'm trying to add new data inside abc div class

```
var html = '<div class="wrapper"><div class="abc"></div></div>';

if (someData == "YES"){

  var newHTML = '<div>hello</div>';
  $(html).find(".abc").html(newHTML);

}

$(body).html(html);
```

How to get updated HTML ?

Comment: the last line `$(body).html(html);` will erase what you done in the "someData" if;
the $ syntax is wrong `$(element)`  in your case $("body"). or $("body").find(".abc"); By the way your abc div need to be created before doing the someData if.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is because you create a jQuery object from the string in the `html`, and you amend that object, but you do not store a reference to it anywhere.

When you call `$(body).html()` you're appending *the original string*, not the jQuery object which you changed. As such you need to change your logic to this:

```js
var html = '<div class="wrapper"><div class="abc"></div></div>';
var $html = $(html); // create the jQuery object and store a reference to it

// alternatively the above can be made in to one line:
// var $html = $('<div class="wrapper"><div class="abc"></div></div>');        

if (someData == "YES") {
  var newHTML = '<div>hello</div>';
  $html.find(".abc").html(newHTML); // amend the jQuery object
}

$(body).html($html); // add the updated HTML to the DOM
```

Answer (score 1):

**Are you looking this?**

```js
var someData = 'YES';

var html = '<div class="wrapper"><div class="abc"></div></div>';

$('#testDiv').append($(html));


if (someData == "YES"){

  var newHTML = '<div>hello</div>';
  $('#testDiv').find(".abc").html(newHTML);

}
console.log($('#testDiv').html());
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<body>

<div id= "testDiv"></div>

</body>
```

Comment: Yes this method will work, But first this will display the html and then will later append the new content, Why not just in a single time

Comment: Yes this will work but , i wanted to display the content in a single time